# tracking visit count of external url in joomla 1.0

Tags: joomla

i have a website in joomla 1.0. it has some links to external sites (not our domain)
is there an easy way to track the hit count?

any components?

-Vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the default banner component. You can publish the banner module with an image. That has click thru tracking if I remember correctly, but you really should be using 1.5 by now if you have the chance.

Comment: hi Jeepstone. thanks for the answer. these links are present in the main menu not part of an article or module.

-V

Comment: In that case, why don't you try installing Google Analytics? That way you can track everything

Comment: but that can't track external urls

Comment: hmmm isn't there anything on the exit pages that shows where people were heading?